# Can't find a child when it's there

Tags: lua, roblox

**Summarize the problem**
I've been trying to give the Table name to a variable.
Everytime someone clicks a table a **part** with the table name get sent in **TakeToTable**.
I get the **part** name and then go search for that table in the **workspace** to do somethings.

**SearchTable** gives me the right output.

**Table** gives me nil and it's strange cause the name is correct and the part exist in the workspace.

**Describe what you’ve tried**
I've tried writing it in different ways, but I can't come out with anything.

**When appropriate, show some code**

```
while index == 0 do
    i += 1
    SearchTable = ClickDetect.TakeToTable:FindFirstChild("Table"..i)
    
    if SearchTable ~= nil then
        index = 1
    end
end
print(SearchTable)

local Table = game.Workspace.Tables:FindFirstChild(SearchTable)

print (Table)
```

**Example**
If the table it's the "Table12", The SearchTable will give me that exact output, but the variable Table will give me a nil, meaning it hasn't found it, When the table it's there.

[image]

Comment: The parent of all is called `Tables`, but you use `TakeToTable`. If it's supposed to be an ObjectValue, take its `Value`.

Comment: oh yeah. TakeToTable is a group where the wanted table get sent as a part with the table number in the name.
I'm trying to get that part name, that tells me which table is wanted, and find the related table in the workspace.
It's not working tho

Comment: In that case, what exactly is `SearchTable` supposed to do? According to the name, it's a table, and no instance has a table name - all instances have string names.

Comment: @Random SearchTable tries to find the right part name by matching the world "table" with all the numbers. When it finds it, it closes the while cycle and procede to print which table it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while loop, `SearchTable` is set to the instance - however, you need the name. Simply take the name of it when you call `FindFirstChild`.

```lua
while index == 0 do
    i += 1
    SearchTable = ClickDetect.TakeToTable:FindFirstChild("Table"..i)
    
    if SearchTable ~= nil then
        index = 1
    end
end
print(SearchTable)

local Table = game.Workspace.Tables:FindFirstChild(SearchTable.Name) --change here

print (Table)
```

Comment: Could you explain me how? sorry I started coding this week-

Comment: @Karmaidk I just included an example in an edit.